# How to convert object of class : "HTMLInternalDocument" "XMLInternalDocument" into object of class "character" ? (scrapeR package)

Tags: r

How to convert object of class : "HTMLInternalDocument" "XMLInternalDocument" directly  into object of class "character" ? (scrape package)

Comment: Did you mean `scrapeR` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump this into a file and read relevant sections with your favorite method.

```
library(scrapeR)
f = system.file("exampleData", "mtcars.xml", package="XML")
doc = xmlTreeParse(f, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
sink("your.file.txt")
doc
sink()
```

Read in, for instance

```
readLines("your.file.txt")

[1] "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"                                                                           
[2] "<!DOCTYPE dataset SYSTEM \"../DatasetByRecord.dtd\">"                                              
[3] "<!-- Taken from the R distribution, in turn taken from Henderson and Velleman 1981, "              
[4] "     Building multiple regression models interactively, Biometrics 37 391-411 .  "                 
[5] "-->"                                                                                               
[6] "<dataset name=\"mtcars\" numRecords=\"32\" source=\"R Project\">"                                  
[7] "  <variables count=\"11\">"                                                                        
[8] "    <variable unit=\"Miles/gallon\">mpg</variable>"                                                
[9] "    <variable>cyl</variable>"
```