# Convert XMLInternalDocument to character vector

Tags: xml, r

What is the best way to cast an object from the `{XML}` package back to a "normal" R character vector?

For example:

```
require(XML)
doc <- htmlParse("http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html")
class(doc)
# [1] "HTMLInternalDocument" "HTMLInternalDocument" 
# "XMLInternalDocument"  "XMLAbstractDocument"
```

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239119/how-to-convert-object-of-class-htmlinternaldocument-xmlinternaldocument-in) suggestion, I could do this:

```
doc.char <- capture.output(doc)
```

But this seems like a circuitous route. However, I didn't find any other appropriate method. And this bugged me already a few times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want a character vector then use `readLines()` instead of `htmlParse()`. But likely you have a more specific need and then the answer is to use XPath to query `doc`; see `?getNodeSet` (and the syntax `doc["//path"]`) and the examples on that help page.

For your specific question I did

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse("http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html")
showMethods(class=class(doc), where=search())
```

and arrived at

```
as(doc, "character")
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the explanation. `showMethods` and `as` was what I was looking for. Learned sth..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this with `do.call(paste, as.list(capture.output(doc)))`

(I had some issues too and I think you can do it as well with `sapply` as @flodel suggested me here on nodes [NodeSet as character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752622/nodeset-as-character))